# How can I ensure that counter_cache is updated correctly in rails unit tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2, minitest, counter-cache

I've got a normal `counter_cache` set up for my Rails 3.2.6 model. It works flawlessly in the webapp, but fails in unit tests.

The following snippet illustrates the issue at hand:

```
test "counter_cache ..." do
    u = FactoryGirl.create(:customer)
    FactoryGirl.create(:order, :customer => u)

    # u.orders.count == 1; rest is always 0
    assert_equal u.orders.count, u.orders_count  # FAILS!
    assert_equal u.orders.count, u.orders.size   # FAILS!
    assert_equal u.orders.count, u.orders.length # FAILS!
end
```

*Note that I tried the same without the use of FactoryGirl, which still failed.*

**How can I ensure that counter_cache is updated correctly in unit tests?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `u` doesn't know that an order was created that belongs to it, so it hasn't updated its state to reflect that. You have at least two options:

- `reload` the User instance (`u`) after creating the order, since it doesn't know that an Order was added:

  ```
  u.reload
  ```
- Create the Order through the User:

  ```
  u.orders << FactoryGirl.build(:order)
  ```

  (This one may be a bit finicky if you have an `after_create`, or even if you don't—FactoryGirl can do too much and screw things up sometimes).

Comment: Great! Both variants function properly.